# replace multiple words using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to replace one word by an empty space in an input field.

however, I want to be able to replace multiple words with empty space.

basically I need to create a word filter so the users can't type certain words.

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type="text" id="demo" name="demo" onkeyup="myFunction()" onkeydown="myFunction()" />
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var words = "badword1";
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").value; 
    var res = str.replace(words, " ");
    document.getElementById("demo").value = res;

}
</script>
```

I've tried something like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var words = "badword1 || badword2 || bad word3";
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").value; 
    var res = str.replace(words, " ");
    document.getElementById("demo").value = res;
    alert('that word is not allowed!');

}
</script>
```

but this doesn't work.

first, it doesn't replace any given `badword(s)` with `empty space` and second it fires the `aler();` message as soon as I type  the first letter in the input field!

could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: FYI, this is a useless undertaking. People who are going to use bad words will simply omit certain letters and replace them with `-` or `*`, or they'll mis-spell them. Best just to monitor and create an environment/community that discourages such words.

Comment: badword1 || badword2 || bad word3 would be read as a string not as a regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this takes the array of bad words... loops through them creates a global regex that then is used to replace it... compares the original and resulting string if they changed put alert.

```
var badwords = ['badword1','badword2','badword3']; //array of badwords
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").value; 
    var res = str;
    for (var i = badwords.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var badword = badwords[i];
        badWordRegex = new RegExp(badword, 'g');
        res=res.replace(badWordRegex, " ");
    };

    document.getElementById("demo").value = res;

    if (str !== res){
        alert('that word is not allowed!');
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't do anything.

Comment: i think you should provide a jsfiddle?! because my code (the first one) works as is!

Comment: fixed http://jsfiddle.net/8HwyV/ but obviously yours didn't work or you wouldn't be here ;-)

Comment: you are the king.... the first code in my question works as is... I just needed to edit to do what you did with it. hats off sir.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
var words = new RegExp("badword1|badword|bad word3", g);
```

ACtually you shouldn't trust client-side code...

Comment: this works but still the alert(); message pops up with the first letter. as for client-side code, this will combined with <noscript> so if the user doesn't have the javascript enabled then they will be directed to another page.

Comment: @user3716307 "the first letter" of what? I don't understand.  ANd please see edit

Comment: first letter of anything i type into the inputfield demo will trigger the alert(); message. and your edit doesn't work.. your previous code worked though.